# Multiple conditional sum columns on one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table structured as below:

```
id  |sourceid |item |freq |siteid |customerid
61  |226      |2    |1    |262    |1  
301 |226      |1    |1    |262    |1  
495 |1        |32   |1    |262    |1  
658 |166      |8    |16   |262    |1  
1   |2        |4    |1    |333    |2
```

I'm trying to add together the sum of "item", based on the value of "freq", grouped by "customerid" and then "siteid"

So in the above, site 262 for customer 1, the sum of items with a freq of 1 is 35 (2+1+32)
I need to do the same for other frequencies
I have the below

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `new_view` AS
    SELECT 
        `siteitems`.`customerID` AS `CID`,
        `siteitems`.`siteID` AS `AID`,
        SUM(`siteitems`.`item`) AS `Semi-annual`
    FROM
        `contractitems` `siteitems`
    WHERE
        (`siteitems`.`freq` = 1)
    GROUP BY `siteitems`.`customerID` , `siteitems`.`siteID`
```

Which gives me the 1 column for frequencies of 1
I'm not sure how I add another column from the same table where the frequency is 2, etc.

Should I remove the WHERE clause and change the SUM (somehow) to just sum the right frequencies or do I need to join the table again?

Comment: Please show the results you want.

Comment: `DEFINER = root@localhost` tell me this is a test.. i assume you don't use the root account on a live server? Using the root account is a huge security issue when you have some kind of SQL injection bug... SQL injection bug is already worse enough scenario but SQL injections under the root account is the worst scenario.

Comment: Yes it's just a test server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, this should do what you want:

```
select customerid, siteid, freq, sum(item)
from contractitems ci
group by customerid, siteid, freq
order by customerid, siteid, freq;
```

However, you might also want conditional aggregation:

```
select customerid, siteid,
       sum(case when freq = 1 then item else 0 end) as item_1,
       sum(case when freq = 2 then item else 0 end) as item_2,
       sum(case when freq = 4 then item else 0 end) as item_4,
       sum(case when freq = 8 then item else 0 end) as item_8,
       sum(case when freq = 16 then item else 0 end) as item_16
from contractitems ci
group by customerid, siteid
order by customerid, siteid;
```

Comment: I used a variation of the second answer  
    SUM(IF((`siteitems`.`freq` = 2),  
    `siteitems`.`item`,  
    0)) AS `Quarterly`  
I'll try the first as that looks similar and I may be over complicating things